# Java get compile-time safe method name

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, metaprogramming, compile-time

While working with the reflection class and annotations I have found that there is no clear way to reference a method name in a compile-time safe way. What I really want is to be able to reference a method within an annotation. Might look something like:

```
@CallAfter(method=Foo.class.foo())
void Bar() { ... }
```

At the moment you can only do this with strings, which is not compile time safe.. This is a problem because it undermines Java being statically typed. The only solution I have found is something like what is below. However this still does not help with referencing a method in an annotation. :(

```
public static String methodName = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // .foo() is compile-time safe
    loadMethodName(IFoo.class).foo();
    System.out.println(methodName);
}

public static <T> T loadMethodName(Class<T> mock) {
    return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(mock.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { mock }, 
    (obj, method, args) -> {
        methodName = method.getName();
        return null;
    });
}

public interface IFoo {
    Object foo();
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts, comments, or a solution to this?

Comment: I you can make Strings compile time safe if you add compile time checks via [annotation processing](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101/) similar to [this here](http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2009/07/09/Enforcing-design-rules-with-the-Pluggable-Annotation-Processor).

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there's no out-of-the-box way to do this.

Comment: Nice this would solve my problem. Kinda sucks I would have to go all the way out to annotation processing, but hey I guess if there is no other solution. Thank you for the advise and the links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use annotations in Java to replace accessors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348408/is-there-a-way-to-use-annotations-in-java-to-replace-accessors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write an `AnnotationProcessor` that can provide a compile-safe method reference. [See it on github](https://github.com/XDean/Annotation-EX)

It will give a compile error if the referenced method not exists.

And it works in eclipse, see the snapshot.

[image: eclipse-use]