# i want to create an annotation processor which will generate javadoc from annotated 'ConfigProperty'

Tags: java, annotations, comments, metaprogramming, javadoc

I want to create an annotation processor that will generate configuration reference from javadoc in source code. I would like to be able to annotate configuration properties in the source and extract the javadoc so that it can be published as configuration reference material.

For eg. if i have an annotation like..

```
/**
 * This is to test annotation processor to extract javadoc.
 * <p>
 * I am trying to extract the javadoc whenever there is an annotation @ConfigProperty.
 * <p>
 * This is to test annotation processor to extract javadoc. 
*/
@ConfigProperty(component="XYZ", section="some section")
public static final String TEST = "my test annotation";
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: OK. So what have you already accomplished and what is your question?

Comment: I have a project, which contains lot of java classes. In those class, if there is an annotation @ConfigProperty, then, whatever comment is there above it should be converted into javadoc. I'm starting this new project to do what i explained. I reviewed few documentation regarding annotation processing, but i'm not understanding how I can extract javadoc using annotation processing. It will be helpful if you can guide me through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use annotations in Java to replace accessors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348408/is-there-a-way-to-use-annotations-in-java-to-replace-accessors)